# Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, fluent-nhibernate

Is there some lightweight framework with ModelBinders to bind NHibernate Models with validation?

Comment: You don't have to use TransferFormValuesTo at all, use view models and/or AutoMapper instead. You better look at http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com for better practices.

Answer (score 0):

How about just ASP.NET MVC & NHibernate? Not sure what you are expecting the 'framework' to do.  For instance what do you mean model binders to bind to NHibernate Model?  NHibernate just uses normal POCOs, so you can bind to them already.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NHibernate Validator](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/01/nhibernate-validator.aspx). It lets you add attributes like `[NotNull]` to your domain model classes, which affect your schema generation and can be validated against like so:

```
var invalidValues = engine.Validate(blog);
foreach (var invalidValue in invalidValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0}: {1}",
        invalidValue.PropertyName, 
        invalidValue.Message);
}
```